# Is there a way to remove a layer from a JSON object?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Is there a way to remove a parent layer from a JSON object?  For example, let's say I have the following JSON object:

```
{
    "Hello": "World",
    "Parent": {
        "key1": "val1",
        "key2": "val2",
        "key3": {
            "key3a": "val3a",
            "key3b": "val3b"
        },
        "key4": "val4"
    }
}
```

But I want to remove the `Parent` layer and have the JSON object read like the following:

```
{
    "Hello": "World",
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "key3": {
        "key3a": "val3a",
        "key3b": "val3b"
    },
    "key4": "val4"
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

I would preferably like to accomplish this using Python, but if anyone knows of a way I am open to using other methods to get this done.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: @JoschJava Apparently Python

Comment: Python.  But I can write this as an AWS Lambda Function so I would also be able to write this in Java8 or Node.js 10 if need be.

Comment: You say "JSON object"; do you want to modify a file containing this JSON, or a data structure instantiated *from* JSON?

Comment: A data structure instantiated from JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be done quite easily with [`dict.pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) and [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

```
import json

data = {
    "Hello": "World",
    "Parent": {
        "key1": "val1",
        "key2": "val2",
        "key3": {
            "key3a": "val3a",
            "key3b": "val3b"
        },
        "key4": "val4"
    }
}

data.update(data.pop("Parent"))

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> {
>    "Hello": "World",
>    "key1": "val1",
>    "key2": "val2",
>    "key3": {
>        "key3a": "val3a",
>        "key3b": "val3b"
>    },
>    "key4": "val4"
> }
> ```

This also has the advantage that this will work for pretty much any version of Python.

Comment: @mattc-7 Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this (dictionary merging, intoduced in Python 3.5):

```
d = {**d.pop('Parent'), **d}
```

Proof:

```
import json

d = {
    "Hello": "World",
    "Parent": {
        "key1": "val1",
        "key2": "val2",
        "key3": {
            "key3a": "val3a",
            "key3b": "val3b"
        },
        "key4": "val4"
    }
}

d = {**d.pop('Parent'), **d}

print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))

# {
#   "key1": "val1",
#   "key2": "val2",
#   "key3": {
#     "key3a": "val3a",
#     "key3b": "val3b"
#   },
#   "key4": "val4",
#   "Hello": "World"
# }
```

Comment: @Loïc Seeing OP will use AWS lambda, that should not be an issue.

Comment: Sure, it's just a precision for anyone trying this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by copying the dict, deleting the `'Parent'` key, and then updating with the contents of the `'Parent'` dict. If there are any keys with the same name, the values from the `'Parent'` dict will override those from the outer dict.

```py
def flatten_dict(data, key):
    new_data = dict(data)
    del new_data[key]
    new_data.update(data[key])
    return new_data
```

Then call `flatten_dict(data, 'Parent')`. This will return the result as a new dict without mutating the original dict.